# How do i push an item back into a stack that i just popped without creating an infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, stack

I'm trying to create a loop for a game in Java with the following logic:

```
if (the stack is not empty) {
 pop top move from stack.
 reset the board.
}

// then i create a while loop to pop the moves back onto the board.

while(stack is not empty) {
   type userMove = history.pop();
   assign userMove back onto the board.
}
```

The last bit I'm stuck on is also pushing the user moves that i'm assigning back into the stack.

if i do this:

```
while(stack is not empty) {
 type userMove = history.pop();
 assign userMove back onto the board. 
 history.push(userMove);
}
```

then i'll create an infinite loop. So i'm not sure how to do that final step to push those moves back into the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is not good fit here.
You can use a double ended queue or Deque.

```
top = deque.removeFromLast();

while(deque.peek() != top) {
 type userMove = deque.removeFromLast();
 assign userMove back onto the board. 
 deque.addToFront(userMove);
}
```